# AWS ECS: OutOFMemoryError: Container killed due to memeroy usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, batch-processing

I'm using AWS BAtch Job with ECS and EC2.
This is the serverless template that i'm using:

```yaml
Description: >
Setup
  AWS Batch Compute Enviornment
  AWS Batch Job Definition
  AWS Batch Queue

Parameters: 
ComputeEnvironmentName:
Description: The batch compute enviornment name to use
Type: String
PlatformVpcStackName:
Description: VPC stack name for export subnets
Type: String
JobDefinitionName:
Description: Batch Job Definition name
Type: String
ECRRepositoryName:
Description: ECR Repository Name
Type: String
JobQueueName:
Description: Batch Job Queue Name
Type: String
EnvironmentName:
Description: Environment name e.g. dev, staging, prod
Type: String
Default: dev
ComponentName:
Description: A name where this resource is created for
Type: String
PartName:
Description: The name of the component's part
Type: String

Resources:
ASGLaunchTemplate:
Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
Properties:
  LaunchTemplateData:
    MetadataOptions:
      HttpEndpoint: enabled
      HttpTokens: required
  TagSpecifications:
    - ResourceType: launch-template
      Tags:
      - Key: STAGE
        Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
      - Key: COMPONENT_NAME
        Value: !Ref ComponentName
      - Key: PART_NAME
        Value: !Ref PartName
      - Key: StackID
        Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackId'

tttCommonParserBatchComputeEnvironment:
Type: 'AWS::Batch::ComputeEnvironment'
Properties:
  ComputeEnvironmentName: !Ref ComputeEnvironmentName
  ComputeResources:
    MaxvCpus: 2
    MinvCpus: 0
    InstanceRole: !GetAtt tttHandlerEcsInstanceProfile.Arn
    InstanceTypes:
      - a1.medium
    DesiredvCpus: 2
    LaunchTemplate:
      LaunchTemplateId: !Ref ASGLaunchTemplate
    Tags:
      'STAGE' : !Ref EnvironmentName
      'COMPONENT_NAME' : !Ref ComponentName
      'PART_NAME' : !Ref PartName
      'StackID' : !Ref 'AWS::StackId'
  State: ENABLED
  Type: MANAGED
  Tags:
    'STAGE' : !Ref EnvironmentName
    'COMPONENT_NAME' : !Ref ComponentName
    'PART_NAME' : !Ref PartName
    'StackID' : !Ref 'AWS::StackId'

BatchJobDefinition:
Type: AWS::Batch::JobDefinition
Properties:
  Type: container
  JobDefinitionName: !Ref JobDefinitionName
  RetryStrategy: 
    Attempts: 1
  Timeout:
    AttemptDurationSeconds: 300
  ContainerProperties:
    JobRoleArn: !Ref tttHandlerJobServiceRole
    Image: !Sub ${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/testing
    Vcpus: 1
    Memory: 256
  Tags: {
    "STAGE" :  !Ref EnvironmentName,
    "COMPONENT_NAME" : !Ref ComponentName,
    "PART_NAME" : !Ref PartName,
    "StackID" : !Ref 'AWS::StackId'
    }

BatchJobQueue: 
Type: "AWS::Batch::JobQueue"
Properties:
  JobQueueName: !Ref JobQueueName
  Priority: 1
  State: ENABLED
  ComputeEnvironmentOrder:
    - Order: 1
      ComputeEnvironment: !Ref tttCommonParserBatchComputeEnvironment
  Tags:
    'STAGE' : !Ref EnvironmentName
    'COMPONENT_NAME' : !Ref ComponentName
    'PART_NAME' : !Ref PartName
    'StackID' : !Ref 'AWS::StackId'

tttCommonParserEcsInstanceRole:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
  RoleName: !Join ["-", [!Ref EnvironmentName, !Ref ComponentName, !Ref PartName, "ttt-common-parser-ecsInstanceRole"] ]
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Statement:
      - Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service: [ec2.amazonaws.com]
    Version: '2012-10-17'
  Path: /        
  ManagedPolicyArns:
    - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
  Tags:
    - Key: STAGE
      Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
    - Key: COMPONENT_NAME
      Value: !Ref ComponentName
    - Key: PART_NAME
      Value: !Ref PartName
    - Key: StackID
      Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackId'

tttHandlerEcsInstanceProfile:
  Type: "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile"
  Properties:
    Path: "/"
    Roles:
      - !Ref tttCommonParserEcsInstanceRole

tttHandlerJobServiceRole:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
  RoleName: !Join ["-", [!Ref EnvironmentName, !Ref ComponentName, !Ref PartName, "ttt-common-parser-jobServiceRole"] ]
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Statement:
      - Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service: [ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com]
    Version: '2012-10-17'
  Path: /
```

When I run single batch job, it runs withourt any issue. However, If I run multiple batch job (2-3), then some of them fails with Error: **AWS ECS: OutOFMemoryError: Container killed due to memeroy usage**

I referred to this article for clarity: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ecs-resolve-outofmemory-errors#:%7E:text=To%20troubleshoot%20OutOfMemory%20errors%20in,occur%20due%20to%20memory%20usage

By reading the article, I understand if a container uses memory more than the host machine, then I'll get the error. However, I'm using **a1.medium** ec2 instance, and it has 2GB memory and 1 vCPU, and my cotnainer uses 1 vCPU and 256MB memory. So this issue should not come. I looked into the ECS Metrics. That confirms the memory is not issue.
[image]

**UPDATE 1:**

After digging and playing around with ECS and Batch, I have realized the following things:

1. Eash of my task need 136MB of memory.
2. When there are multiple batch batch job/task, single container is re-used instead of new container for each task. Due to this when 2nd task is started within same container, its memory is already at 136MB used, so total memory required now: 136 + 136 = 272MB which is more than allowed(256MB).

I'm thinking about following ways to solve it if it is possible:

1. For each task, there should be 1 container instantiated instead of re-using the old one, even when they are running in parallel.
2. Container's memory should increase dynamically depending upon the load. Something with the EC2 Auto Scaling Groups.

Not sure how to achieve them yet.

Comment: It's possible your memory usage increases faster than your cloudwatch metric interval period (usually 60 seconds) can display. So, if your application can buildup enough memory usage to surpass the limit (256M) faster than 1 minute, you may never see that reflected in metrics. I doubt the OOM killer is lying to you. Also -- are you setting the container memory **limit** or memory **reservation** to 256M? The former is a hard limit (irrespective if the host has more memory available), the latter is a soft limit (allows breaking the limit as long as the host has available memory).

Comment: its memory. Is it possible for batch job to auto re-try with increase memory limit if it has failed dueo to out of memory...something limit auto scaling ? or any way that the memroy is automatically increase depending upon the work load ?